# Do you know of software for automatic waveform compliance checking?

Tags: fpga, waveform, logic-analyzer

do you know of any software which can be used to automatically check a measured waveform (from a logic analyzer/scope) against some specification? For example I measured some pulse with a logic analyzer and the program can automatically check if this is a single pulse with a length  between 1 ms and 2 ms. It then gives me a pass or fail output.

I would also like to know if there is a special term for what I call "waveform compliance checking".

An ideal program would:

- read a textual specification
- read a well known waveform format (e.g. vcd)
- be open source
- run from a terminal such that it can be integrated into an automatic test bench

Comment: what about the "pass check" functionality of virtually every modern DSO?

Comment: Thank you. A DSO is not flexible enough for my use case since the waveforms are from different sources and measured automatically. I cannot buy a DSO for each measurement :-) (I edited the question to only ask for software.)

Comment: Numerous DSOs have a user definable mask feature.

Comment: @Alexander Usually you write a script that will set the scope up via a VISA interface which most scopes have, almost any feature is controllable via software, oscilloscopes have features for waveform checking.  If that doesn't work then get any DAQ that is suitable for your bandwidth and import the waveform into matlab, C or python and write some software to check the waveform. At 1-2ms you won't need a very fast DAQ if you need many signals.

Comment: (Some people put the question on hold) Really guys, it is off-topic to ask for something to support automatic hardware testing? You think this is NOT an electronic design technique? Welcome to the 21st century!

Answer (score 0):

For vhdl, another quick option is to create your "ideal output wave" generator, and create another circuit to calculate the difference with the real output, you can even consider an acceptable error. Then integrate them in your testbench.